# creating new array from multidimensional arrays -next step

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I searched all options for it, without success.

I have my Multidimensional Array like this:

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Title1" 
        [1] => "Title2"
        [2] => "Title3"
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Title1"  
        [1] => "Title2"
    )
)
 Array #2

  Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Value1"  
        [1] => "Value2"
        [2] => "Value3"
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Value" 
        [1] => "Value2"
    )
)
```

And I would like to achive result like this:

```
New Array

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
      [0] =>Array
          (
        [0] => "Title1"  
        [1] => "Title2"
        [2] => "Title3"
          )
          (
      [1] =>Array
          (
        [0] => "Title1"  
        [1] => "Title2"
          )
 )
 (

[1] => Array
    (
      [0] =>Array
          (
        [0] => "Value1"  
        [1] => "Value2"
        [2] => "Value3"
          )
          (
      [1] =>Array
          (
        [0] => "Value"  
        [1] => "Value2"
          )
    )
)
```

So I want to add 1 level of array, My thinking way is to loop through multidimensional array(2 loops) and by 3 loop add 2 next(on this example) array within. array_merge_recursive will not work. I tried to create proper loop, but without success. Is it possible??

Comment: I might be misreading, but do you just want to put both arrays into a single one? `$newArray = [$array1, $array2];` ?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: $array = array( $array1, $array2 ); do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below (***Assign both arrays to a new array***):-

```
$arr3 = array($arr1,$arr2); // or [$arr1,$arr2];
print_r($arr3);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/838283

Comment: Is it just so simple? :) I have something similar now, I will try to work with it in ajax. I think it will be accomplished with that. But the first of all, you tips are priceless. Thank you!

Comment: @Michał  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this-

```
$finalArray=[$arr1,$arr2]
```

Then you can add more array like

```
 $finalArray[] = $arr3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge() function

```
array_merge(array1,array2);
```

Comment: I don't think it will work.check with OP's array.Check here:- https://eval.in/838288